# Error al descargar archivo desde página ASPX

Tags: google-chrome, descarga

Buenas tardes,

Estoy intentando descargar un archivo desde una página aspx creada por mi. Al intentar descargar desde Google Chrome me aparece el mensaje: "Error: Error de Red".

[image: Pantalla de error]

El fragmento del código que estoy utilizando es el siguiente:

```html
<a href="c:\users\egodoy\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\PreCREDITPRO.Manager\PreCREDITPRO.Manager\archivosCargados\12 20160926 003621Mantenimiento Tablas.sql" class="list-group-item" download>Mantenimiento Tablas.sql</a>
```

Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score -1):

En un link de descarga no puedes poner una ruta fisica de la pc, tiene que ser un link al archivo en el sitio web

algo como ser

```
<a href="archivosCargados/12 20160926 003621Mantenimiento Tablas.sql" class="list-group-item" download>Mantenimiento Tablas.sql</a>
```

como veras es una ruta que armara un http://sitio/carpeta/archivo.sql esa es la estructura, los link nunca empiezan con c:\

Comment: Utilizando la URI `file:` si es posible.

Comment: @Davlio esta en un entorno web, el archivo esta en el servidor en un sitio, el uri file no aplica, el sitio no esta en una red local, y aunque lo este no se accede de esa forma a un archivo

Comment: Entiendo tu punto de vista, a lo que voy es que un sitio web si tiene el alcance de acceder a un archivo local de una PC pero tiene su limitante.